# ionic 2 - stop a click event

Tags: angular, ionic2

Here is my html:

```
<ion-card *ngIf="oefening1" (click)="navigate($event, oefening1, oefening2, oefening3, oefening4)">
   <img src="assets/img/{{ oefening1 }}.jpg"/>
   <div *ngFor="let exercise of exerciseIsDone;">  
   <div *ngIf="exercise.done && exercise.exercise == oefening1" class="overlay">
      <ion-icon name="checkmark-circle" class="checkmark"></ion-icon>
   </div>
</div>
```

I have an function like this:

```
navigate(event, exercise, exercise2, exercise3, exercise4){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.exerciseIsDone.length; i++) {
          console.log('forLoop: ',this.exerciseIsDone[i]);

          if(this.exerciseIsDone[i].done){
             console.log(event.stopPropagation());
             event.stopPropagation();

             console.log(event.target);
             console.log('DONE!!!!!');
           }
    }


  this.navCtrl.push(exerciseSlides, {
            clickedExercise: exercise,
            secondExercise: exercise2,
            thirdExercise: exercise3,
            fourthExercise: exercise4
  });
}
```

But it will stil execute and the `console.log(event.stopPropagation());` is undefined.

So basically what I want to do is when the exercise is done it shouldn't be clickable(not navigating to the next page) anymore. How can I fix this??

And the `target` log says that `<div class="overlay">` I don't know if this is causing the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have some assumptions.

**First**, you say that

> `target` log says that `<div class="overlay">`

I think you clicked on that element. If you had clicked one the `<img>` tag the `target` would have printed `<img>`

**Second**, I don't know why you use `event.stopPropagation()`. It is used in the mechanism called *Event Bubbling*. As we read from the documentation.

> When an event happens on an element, it first runs the handlers on it, then on its parent, then all the way up on other ancestors.

So your `event.stopPropagation()` will stop spreading the event to a parent of the element. If you just want to stop the invocation of the function right there you can simply do this:

```
if(this.exerciseIsDone[i].done){
    return;
}
```

But, if you want to just stop the for loop you can do it this way:

```
if(this.exerciseIsDone[i].done){
    break;
}
```

@edit
Full example:

```
navigate(event, exercise, exercise2, exercise3, exercise4){
    for (var i = 0; i < this.exerciseIsDone.length; i++) {
          console.log('forLoop: ',this.exerciseIsDone[i]);

          if(this.exerciseIsDone[i].done){
             return; //immediately stops invocation of this function
           }
    }


  this.navCtrl.push(exerciseSlides, {
            clickedExercise: exercise,
            secondExercise: exercise2,
            thirdExercise: exercise3,
            fourthExercise: exercise4
  });
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation but now all cards are not executing the function. How can I write an if statement to only return on the done exercise?

Comment: When i use return

Comment: Well, I don't understand what you mean, but I think that maybe this is the problem: `if(this.exerciseIsDone[i]){
    return;
}` try to remove `.done`, because from the name `excersiceIsDone[i]` I assume it is an array of booleans. I might be wrong, but I can't help you without the full context (what does `this.excerciseIsDone` store?)

Comment: this is what it stores: `Object
done
:
true
exercise
:
"lagerugklacht"
path
:
"assets/img/lagerugklacht.jpg"
`

Comment: Ok, lets start from the beginning. You iterate over all you excercises. If one of them is done, what do you want to do?

Comment: Than the overlay is vissible in the html of the card. Than if it is done I don't want to execute the navigate function anymore because it is done. So for the other cards I put only one in this example it has to be executed if they aren't dont.

Comment: If all your cards use the same function then they all use the same `this.exerciseIsDone` array. So if you want every card to use different set of excercises you should pass it as a function parameter.

Comment: I don't know if I understood you problem correctly, but I'll be willing to provide more help if you put an example on for example: [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/143567/discussion-between-humberd-and-sreinieren).

Answer (score 1):

stopPropagation() function returns void, so the line will print undefined

```
   console.log(event.stopPropagation());
```

> stopPropagation - Prevents further propagation of the current event in
>   the capturing and bubbling phases.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Event/stopPropagation

So stopPropagation will stop event propagation to parents and grand parents of this dom element.

If you want to make this dom not clickable, you need to add/remove event listener manually.

You can implement click.one directive that you can use like that:

```
 <h2 (click-once)="handle($event)>Click me once</h2>


@Directive({
  selector: '[click.once]'
})
export class ClickOnce {
  @Output('click.once') clickOnce = new EventEmitter();
  unsubscribe;

  constructor(private renderer: Renderer, private el: ElementRef) {
  }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.unsubscribe = this.renderer.listen(this.el.nativeElement, 'click', event => {
      this.unsubscribe();
      this.unsubscribe = null;
      this.clickOnce.emit(event);
    });
  }


  ngOnDestroy() {
    if (this.unsubscribe) {
      this.unsubscribe();
    }
  }
}
```